# how to use strace on windows operating system

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, strace

i have been searching for it from 2 weeks. i have installed strace from here (https://sourceforge.net/projects/strace/?source=navbar) 
i want to trace system calls of android apps installed on android device using strace. currently i have Windows 8.1 installed on my laptop. do i have to install Linux on my machine? or i can simply use strace with eclipse without installing Linux??
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `strace` is Linux syscalls tracer so it can only be used on Linux or maybe [`Cygwin`](https://www.cygwin.com/). Also, if you are tracing syscalls on Android, why are you installing it on your laptop?

Comment: Strace is new tool for me. I have read that strace is a linux tool and is used for system call tracing in android so i thought that may be i need to install linux first. Can i trace the system calls of android apps just by using eclipse and without installing linux?

Comment: I have downloaded strace and now i dont have any clue about what to do next. neither i find any tutorial about what to do. there is no any .exe file in the folder strace-4.15. All i can find is linux commands over the internet to use strace. please tell me what to do with this downloaded strace tool and what else i need to install for tracing system calls of android application.

Comment: Not sure you can use the tool as is to trace syscalls of Android applications and I don't think you can use it on Eclipse. You may need to look into how those guys did it in their paper [here](https://doi.org/10.1109/WOCC.2014.6839912). They traced Android intent actions (syscalls). Hope that helps